# XPathExpression to select from tesseract hOCR XML output

Tags: java, xpath, tesseract, jdom-2

I have a file of roughly the following shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name='ocr-system' content='tesseract 3.02' />
  <meta name='ocr-capabilities' content='ocr_page ocr_carea ocr_par ocr_line ocrx_word'/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='ocr_page' id='page_1' title='image "D:\DPC2\converted\60\60.tiff"; bbox 0 0 2479 3508; ppageno 0'>
       <!-- LOTS OF CONTENT -->
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then I am using JDOM 2.x with the following XPath query:

```
//htmlFile is an input variable of type java.nio.Path
Document document = xmlBuilder.build(htmlFile.toFile());

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.instance();
XPathExpression<Element> xpePages = 
    factory.compile("//html/body/div[@class='ocr_page']", Filters.element());
List<Element> pages = xpePages.evaluate(document);
```

But it is never able to find any elements, what am I doing wrong in query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespaces.

The `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` means that elements with no prefix in the XML file are actually in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace, and you need to specify this in the XPath expression using a prefix:

```
XPathExpression<Element> xpePages = 
    factory.compile("/h:html/h:body/h:div[@class='ocr_page']",
                    Filters.element(),
                    null, // no variables
                    Namespace.getNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"));
```

You must use a prefix, as in XPath no prefix always means no namespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Means that elements like `html` are in namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`

You've got a couple of ways forward

- To register a `NamespaceContext` (~name space manager), which looks rather onerous in this technology stack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390494/314291
- Alternatively to use namespace-agnostic xpath, e.g.

```
 //*[local-name()=='html' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']
 /*[local-name()='body' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']
 /* ... etc.
```

If you are confident that there is no conflict in the namespaces of the elements, you can choose to use just `local-name()`

```
//*[local-name()=='html']/*[local-name()='body']* ...
```

Comment: This is the JDOM `XPathFactory`, not the `javax.xml.xpath` one - namespaces are much easier in JDOM.