# XPath evaluation with Saxon doesn't work for nodename

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

Why doesn't the following xpath return any results with Saxon 9.6 in Java?

`//field`

The strange part is I also evaluated `//*` and looped over the results comparing the nodeNames with "field" and got 889 hits for my document.

Full codeexample below:

Initializing and running the test:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);


test(doc, "//*");
test(doc, "//field");
```

Test execution code:

```
private void test(Document doc, String xpathString) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:" + NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON, "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl");
    XPathFactory xpf;
    xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);

    XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathString);

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    int fieldHits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        String name = node.getNodeName();
        fieldHits = "field".equals(nodes.item(i).getNodeName()) ? fieldHits + 1 : fieldHits;
    }

    System.out.println("#hits total: " + nodes.getLength());
    System.out.println("#hits 'field': " + fieldHits);
}
```

Output:

```
#hits total: 26256
#hits 'field': 889
#hits total: 0
#hits 'field': 0
```

Example XML-File (thanks to wero I now know it has something to do with namespaces):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xfa generator="AdobeLiveCycleDesignerES_V9.0.1.0.20091206.1.615263" APIVersion="3.2.9310.0"?>
<xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/" timeStamp="2015-11-17T07:12:49Z" uuid="262c190c-1563-4ae8-ae6e-4c8d59494a3c">
<template xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.8/">
    <field name="A"></field>
    <field name="B"></field>
    <field name="C"></field>
    <field name="D"></field>
    <field name="E"></field>
    <field name="F"></field>
</template>
</xdp:xdp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your `field` elements have a non-null namespace uri and therefore aren't matched by your XPath expression.

EDIT:

As I guessed your document declares the default namespace

```
xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.8/"
```

and so the `template` and `field` elements are in that namespace.

To match the `field` elements you either need to [tweak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390339/how-to-query-xml-using-namespaces-in-java-with-xpath) your XPath query to also declare that namespace or search for the local name only.

Comment: Thanks, it definitly has something to do with namespaces. Now I could create a simple example. Could you take a look at it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you were to use the s9api interface instead of JAXP, you could take advantage of the ability in XPath 2.0 to set a default namespace for element names in the XPath expression. Your code would then look like this:

```
private void test(Document doc, String xpathString) throws Exception {
    Processor proc = new Processor(false);
    XdmNode docNode = proc.newDocumentBuilder().wrap(doc);
    XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
    xpath.declareNamespace("", "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.8/"); 
    XdmValue result = xpath.evaluate(xpathString, docNode);
    int fieldHits = 0;
    for (XdmItem item : result) {
        String name = ((XdmNode)node).getNodeName().getLocalName();
        fieldHits = "field".equals(name) ? fieldHits + 1 : fieldHits;
    }

    System.out.println("#hits total: " + nodes.getLength());
    System.out.println("#hits 'field': " + fieldHits);
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the s9api, will take a look into it. Thanks :)