# Java XML parsing with SAX and XPath when tags have ":"

Tags: java, xpath, sax

Does anyone know why this does not work in XPath?

```
 String expression = "/*/*/packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Class']";
```

but this does

```
String expression = "/*/*/packagedElement[@name='Operator']";
```

Aparently when I use tags with ":" (either in the attribute e.g. xmi:type or uml:Class, or both), I get no answer.

What should I do?

Many thanks!

Madalina

Comment: XML tags with `:` are using [*namespaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). You should read about XPath support for namespace, e.g. [How to query XML using namespaces in Java with XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6390339/5221149)

Comment: did you define namespaces for xmi: prefix? Does namespace match namespace declared in XML? Are  you sure your xmi:type always has exact string as 'uml:Class' can it be like 'ns1:Class'? Maybe you can try [contains(@xmi:type, 'Class')] ?