# Cannot replace node value

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap

I have a SOAP message as as string which looks like:

```
 String testMsg = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"><soap:Header>Some Header stuff</soap:Header><soap:Body>Some Body Stuff</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
```

Then it goes to XPath but can't find a node (came as null) to set text value

```
    Document doc = convertStringToDocument(testMsg);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String expression = "//soap:Envelope/soap:Body";
    Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

    // Set the node content
    node.setTextContent("Body was removed");
```

I try to convert it to XML document using method below

```
private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    try
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr));
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);

        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390339/how-to-query-xml-using-namespaces-in-java-with-xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should redirect your question to IDE debugger. For me such code snippet works properly. For example, I can output text inside `Header` tags like so

```
System.out.println(
        doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", "Header")
        .item(0).getTextContent());
```

It outputs expected `Some Header stuff`. In your case I think you'd printed `Document` instance itself and saw result like `[#document: null]` which confused you. But the truth is that the object exist.

**UPDATE**
You forget to let `XPath` be aware of your namespace. This will do that you want.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if ("soap".equals(prefix)) {
            return "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
        }
        return null;
    }
});

String expression = "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body";
Node node = (Node) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
node.setTextContent("Body was removed");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Exactly - I see `[#document: null]` but then that document cannot be used with XPath as it came as null pointer

Comment: @JackTheKnife, update your question with code snippet which is not working for you. For now - you're not getting `null`, you have object instance as expected. Also as you can see from my answer it's perfectly navigable using traditional DOM API.

Comment: OK, my question was updated to current state based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to set

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
```

and then update XPath code to

```
String expression = "/Envelope/Body";
Node node = (Node) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Hope it will help somebody else.