# how to parse xml to java in nodelist

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodelist

that is my xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:GetADSLProfileResponse xmlns:ns0 = "http://">
<ns0:Result>
    <ns0:eCode>0</ns0:eCode>
    <ns0:eDesc>Success</ns0:eDesc>
</ns0:Result>
</ns0:GetADSLProfileResponse>
```

that is my code in java I need to know how to start in this 
I tried some code online but still did not solve my problem 
how to get the values in the result to loop in it and get 0 in ecode and Success in eDesc

```
CustomerProfileResult pojo = new CustomerProfileResult();
    String body = readfile();
    System.out.println(body);
    try {  
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(body)));
        XPath xpath =XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        XPathExpression name = xpath.compile("/xml/GetADSLProfileResponse/Result");
        NodeList nodeName = (NodeList) name.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        if(nodeName!=null){

        }
```

Comment: Can you use other libraries?

Comment: any link will be appreciated , thanks

Comment: I've had great experience with JacksonXML. If you can pull in that library, it'll do the low-level parsing for you. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

You can try to following expression which allows you to select nodes without caring the namespace `ns0`:

```
/*[local-name()='GetADSLProfileResponse']/*[local-name()='Result']/*
```

### Explanation

In your syntax, several parts were incorrect. Let's take a look together. XPath syntax `/xml` means that the root node of the document is `<xml>`, but the root element is `<ns0:GetADSLProfileResponse>`; `GetADSLProfileResponse` is incorrect too, because your XML file contains a namespace. Same for `Result`:

```
/xml/GetADSLProfileResponse/Result
```

In my solution, I ignored the namespace, because your namespace provided is incomplet. Here's a full program to get started:

```
String XML =
  "<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding = \"UTF-8\"?>\n"
      + "<ns0:GetADSLProfileResponse xmlns:ns0 = \"http://\">\n"
      + "  <ns0:Result>\n"
      + "    <ns0:eCode>0</ns0:eCode>\n"
      + "    <ns0:eDesc>Success</ns0:eDesc>\n"
      + "  </ns0:Result>\n"
      + "</ns0:GetADSLProfileResponse> ";
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document;
try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
  document = builder.parse(in);
}

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/*[local-name()='GetADSLProfileResponse']/*[local-name()='Result']/*");

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
  Node node = nodeList.item(i);
  System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + ": " + node.getTextContent());
}
```

It prints:

```
ns0:eCode: 0
ns0:eDesc: Success
```

See also:

- [How to query XML using namespaces in Java with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390339/how-to-query-xml-using-namespaces-in-java-with-xpath)
- [Node (Java Platform SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)

Comment: I tried the above answer but when i iterate through it like this 

   for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeValue());
   }

Returns null
do you know why it returns that

Comment: @Bav, both child nodes `eCode` and `eDesc` are element-nodes. An element node returns `null` when using method getNodeValue(). You can use `getTextContent()`. See Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html