# Escaping special characters inside XPATH

Tags: xpath, escaping

I have some elements with the tag `<xxx:element>` inside my xml.

I want to get these using XPath. I've tried a few ways of getting them but so far unsuccessful.

`//xxx:element` just doesn't return anything. I'm guessing this is because of the `:` characater
`//#xxx:element#` gives the exception: "A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token."
`//'xxx:element'` same exception.

Any suggestions?

Based on choroba's answer I found [Xml Namespace breaking my xpath!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution using the local-name property. The following works just fine:
    //*[local-name()='element']

Answer (score 2):

The `xxx:` part is a namespace prefix. It should work in XPath, but depending on the language you are using, you might need to register the namespace before you can use it.

Comment: Not related to this question - Can `x/y[position()=1 or position()= 2]` expression be write in more simple way in `Xpath1.0` and `2.0` also?

Comment: @Babai: Do you mean `x/y[position()<3]` ?

Comment: That's cool.. But if `x/y[position()=1 or position()= 5]` then?

Answer (score 0):

In saxon //*:element do the trick to me