# JXPath expression with escape character '#' giving issues

Tags: java, arrays, json, xpath, jxpath

Input JSON :

```
[
    {"Activity":"yes","SBNumber":"123"},
    {"Activity":"yes","SB#":"123"}
]
```

JXPath Expressions:

```
//works : returns "123"
JXPathContext.newContext(input).getValue("//*/SBNumber")

//fails: throwing JXPathInvalidSyntaxException
JXPathContext.newContext(input).getValue("//*/SB#")
```

How do i escape # to retrieve value from SB# ?

Failed attempts include

```
JXPathContext.newContext(input).getValue("//*/SB\\#")  
JXPathContext.newContext(input).getValue("//*/SB[#]")
JXPathContext.newContext(input).getValue("//*/SB*")
```

etc..

However, I am able to retrieve node from below

```
JXPathContext.newContext(input).getValue("//*/*[contains(.,'SB#')]")
```

But then it is reference to the parent node only :-(

Any possible solution / alternative will be helpful.. tx

Comment: may be this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457960/escaping-special-characters-inside-xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a **context** **variable** can help *escaping* like mentioned below-

```
JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(input);
context.getVariables().declareVariable("blabla", "SB#");
context.getValue("//*/$blabla");
```