# xmlns shows that URI is not absolute, how to have this type of namespace specific xml parsing to r?

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I am a newbie to R and xml, and i would like to fetch some data from a webpage, however, my code fails due to (I guess) xml namespace, (correct me if i am wrong), what should i do to make my code ok?

```
data <- "http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/usda/current/wasde/wasde-01-12-2015.xml"
path <- "//sr15//matrix1//attribute4[@attribute4='Ending Stocks']//m1_year_group[@market_year4='2013/14 Est.']//Cell"
getNodeSet(data,path)
```

returns NULL

Nevertheless, if I parse a different xml without **xmlns="wasde"**, it's possible to read

```
data2 <- "http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/usda/waob/wasde//2010s/2014/wasde-12-10-2014.xml"

getNodeSet(data2,path)
```

Any thought? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath and namespace specification for XML documents with an explicit default namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954792/xpath-and-namespace-specification-for-xml-documents-with-an-explicit-default-nam)

Comment: thanks a lot, that indeed solve my problem

Comment: Hi. I have exactly the same problem for the same dataset! The link wasn't clear to me unfortunately... Is there any chance you would write a hint on the solution you took? Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Matifou, can you be more precise on what blocks you? in fact, I just run through what kjhughes has shared. Let me know if you still have the issue.