# xpathSApply returns empty but xmlValue gives the correct value using XML package in R

Tags: r, xml

Recently, I want to parse XML file using R and the package XML.
After learning from website tutorial, I can obtain the values what I want in the XML specified tag.
But when I want to parse my own xml file ( the file is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yr0klZ0eChTAPmZpnlYL-hQ3-42Sply2). I always obtain the empty list (Actually, I want the value of **PC-ID_id** tag).

```
library(XML)
xml = xmlParse('./100000.xml', useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xpathSApply(xml, '//PC-ID_id', xmlValue)
# list()

xmltop = xmlRoot(xml)
xmlValue(xmltop[['PC-AssaySubmit_assay']]
         [['PC-AssaySubmit_assay_descr']]
         [['PC-AssayDescription']]
         [['PC-AssayDescription_aid']]
         [['PC-ID']]
         [['PC-ID_id']]
)
# "100000"
```

Can you help me figure out what is the reason of empty list returned when using xpathSApply()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely because your XML document uses a default namespace. You need to properly account for that when creating your xpath expression.

The newer `xml2` library makes it easier to strip off the default namespace. So, for example, you can do

```
library(xml2)
read_xml('./100000.xml') %>% 
  xml_ns_strip() %>% 
  xml_find_all("//PC-ID_id") %>% 
  xml_text
# [1] "100000"
```

If you really, really want to use the `XML` package, then check out the possible answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954792/xpath-and-namespace-specification-for-xml-documents-with-an-explicit-default-namespace)

Comment: Thanks so much! First time to know the issue of namespace. Have a great weekend.