# can't get xhtml <script> content with libxml++ using xpath expression

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, libxml2

```
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>

xmlpp::NodeSet xmlP(std::string xml_string, std::string xpath) {

xmlpp::DomParser doc;
// 'response' contains your HTML
doc.parse_memory(xml_string);

xmlpp::Document* document = doc.get_document();
xmlpp::Element* root = document->get_root_node();

xmlpp::NodeSet elemns = root->find(xpath);
xmlpp::Node* element = elemns[0];
std::cout << elemns.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << element->get_line() << std::endl;
//const auto nodeText = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::TextNode*>(element);
const auto nodeText = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::ContentNode*>(element);
if (nodeText && nodeText->is_white_space()) //Let's ignore the indenting - you don't always want to do this.
{
    std::cout << nodeText->get_content() << std::endl;
}
}
```

The xml_string is something like this :

```
std::string xml_strings("
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html lang=\"en\" xml:lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head>
<title>Demo page</title></head>
<body>
<div class=\"item\">
<div class=\"row\">
<div class=\"col-xs-8\">Item</div>
<div class=\"col-xs-4 value\">
<script type=\"text/javascript\">fruit('orange');</script>
</div></div></div>
</body></html>");
```

The function called with the page and the xpath expression like this : `xmlpp::NodeSet xmlNodes = xmlP(xml_strings, "/html/body/div/div/div[2]/script");`

**The problem is i couldn't get the text inside the `<script>`, i tried dynamic_cast'ing to ContentNode, nothing helped...**

is libxml++ worth it or i need to solve my problem with another xml library?

Please, i appreciate all suggestions that can get me the text value from the `<script>` tag.

Comment: See if you can get any output with the XPath expression `//script` first.

Comment: @Botje That is not the only /script in the real document, so using //script might be directed towards a single `<script>`

Comment: If `//script` works then the issue is with your original XPath query and not your XML parser.

Comment: The xPath works, but i couldn't get the content from libxml++, no class method to give me the content; which should be the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing your issue locally and could not get `root->find(xpath)` to produce any nodes.
According to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552800/register-namespace-with-libxml-for-xpath), you need to tell XPath which namespace your nodes are under, even if it is the default namespace.

I changed the XPath string and `find` invocation as follows:

```
std::string xpath("/x:html/x:body/x:div/x:div/x:div[2]/x:script");
xmlpp::Node::PrefixNsMap nsMap = {{"x",root->get_namespace_uri()}};
xmlpp::Node::NodeSet elemns = root->find(xpath, nsMap);

xmlpp::Node* element = elemns[0];
const auto nodeText = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::Element*>(element);
if (nodeText) {
    std::cout << nodeText->get_first_child_text()->get_content() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Comparing your answer with the current implementation i resolved to from one of the test unit implementation, this is the right answer.. Thanks so much, yours is way lighter and more direct than the copy-paste i was trying to use....

Thanks once again

Comment: The namespace is not dynamically changing. It would be better to use just `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Comment: In my usage, I didn't use the name space. Possibly, html-tidy might have added namespace somewhere while cleaning and converting HTML to XML.