# Python xpath - not information from an xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying crawl a website for a bot I'm working on, anyway; I'm not too experienced with xpath and right now I can get some information but from the website that I'm crawling there are guides (Like guides for videogames) (It's a game) and I want to get the title of the guide but it doesn't output anything; I'll explain my code:

```
name = input("> ")

page = requests.get("http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/champions")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

for index, champ in enumerate(champ_list):
    if name == champ:
        y = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='browse-build']/a[{}]/@href".format(index + 1))
        print(y)


guide = requests.get("http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/champion/ashe-13")
builds = html.fromstring(guide.content)
print(builds)

for title in builds.xpath(".//*[@id='browse-build']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/text()"):
    print(title)
```

Ok, from the input it searched a list and from said list it extracts a link which would go on the `guide` variable; from that I want to crawl for the title of the first guide but it doesn't output anything. I get a status code 200 so I know everything is fine with the url and that. I tried nesting this:

```
guide = requests.get("http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/champion/ashe-13")
builds = html.fromstring(guide.content)
print(builds)

for title in builds.xpath(".//*[@id='browse-build']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/text()"):
    print(title)
```

Inside the for loop above but it doesn't do anything neither; literally, it just finishes the program; there you can see the site where I'm getting the information from and that's it; I don't know what would be the right approach to this, if there is anything else I should add please tell me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it's not printing anything, that means it didn't find any elements matching that xpath.  I see that page has two `<div>`s with `id="browse-build"`, but ids are supposed to be unique.  Perhaps that is confusing your search?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah, I see it now, that was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, an **id** must be unique. The first of these constructions works. The fact that the code doesn't actually contain a **tbody** might explain why the second doesn't.

```
>>> for item in builds.xpath(""".//table[@class='browse-table']/tr[1]/td/text()"""):
...     item
...     
'Season 7 Guides'

>>> for item in builds.xpath(""".//table[@class='browse-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td/text()"""):
...     item
...
```

I don't know this provides a path to the results you want, however, since you didn't specify them.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem; I wasn't looking for that result but I got it anyway, thank you!

Comment: Welcome! -----------------

Answer (score 1):

The site has a namespace defined (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml").
You have to add that namespace at these xpath.
For more info visit this.
[Xml Namespace breaking my xpath!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath)