# How to check if node contains a specific value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml file:

```
    <MT_extension>
        <WebDescription xmlns="http://matalan.co.uk/DNArts/">WebDescription</WebDescription>
        <StyleDescription xmlns="http://matalan.co.uk/DNArts/">DVD Style</StyleDescription>
        <PriceStatus xmlns="http://matalan.co.uk/DNArts/">Markdown</PriceStatus>
    </MT_extension>
```

and this is my xsl code:

```
<xsl:variable name="bMarkdownFlag">
  <xsl:if test="./MT_extension/PriceStatus = 'Markdown'">-1</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

I want to check if this `PriceStatus` is Markdown but it always return `false`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml Namespace breaking my xpath!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath)

Comment: The XSL can't find PriceStatus because in your XML, PriceStatus has a namespace assigned to it. You'll have to add a namespace declaration to your xsl.

Comment: What do you mean by `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has @hobbes said you have to *declare* namespace in your XSLT, and use in xpath expression for example

```
<xsl:variable name="bMarkdownFlag" xmlns:dna="http://matalan.co.uk/DNArts/">
    <xsl:if test="./MT_extension/dna:PriceStatus = 'Markdown'">-1</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It Works !