# Unsure about current path in XSLT document when selecting field element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, biztalk

I am in the process of transforming an XML file, using a map based on a subtype in the header.

To make this logic happen I've used an xsl:if inside a template that matches on the root node.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="var:invoiceSubtype" select="//Header/InvoiceType/text()"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="$var:invoiceSubtype = 'Invoice'">
```

Inside the xsl:if I've pasted the XSLT code for the map, without changing the xpath, but some of my elements are not showing any data, like this one:

```
<BELNR>
   <xsl:value-of select="/Header/InvoiceNumber/text()" />
</BELNR>
```

The structure of my schema up until the InvoiceType looks like this:

[image]

Using the double slash to select the element works, but I'd rather avoid using that, since there might be duplicate named elements.

Is there a way of showing where you currently are in the source schema when selecting nodes? I'm unsure as to what the correct path is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change to the full `XPATH` starting from the root to avoid using `//Header/InvoiceType/text()`, use: `/CDM_PurchaseInvoice/Header/InvoiceType/text()` instead.

Also if you are using namespaces you should take it into account in your `xpath` or by using the syntax `/x:List/x:Fields/x:Fiels` or `/*[name()='List']/*[name()='Fields']/*[name()='Field']` otherwise you might end up extracting nothing even if the xpath looks correct at first glance.

see: [Xml Namespace breaking my xpath!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath)

Comment: Using the full XPATH does not work, no data is being shown.

Comment: Could it be a namespace issue?

Comment: @Leth: can you provide the xml file?

Comment: @Leth: high chances that it might be a namespace issue

Comment: @Leth: try the solution at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath

`/x:List/x:Fields/x:Fiels` or `/*[name()='List']/*[name()='Fields']/*[name()='Field']` let me know if it works for your

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by including a prefix I had missed. s0:CDM_PurchaseInvoice/Header/InvoiceType/text()

Comment: @Leth: great it could help you!

Comment: @Leth ...and future readers.  Allen's answer is 100%, but **not for BizTalk**.  It's best to continue this in the original thread.