# How do I write an xpath expression to exctract a string from a node with attribute in it?

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IDMResponse xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" MajorVersion="1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ARTSHeader>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <Response ResponseCode="Ok">
            <RequestID>1</RequestID>
        </Response>
    </ARTSHeader>
</IDMResponse>
```

I tried
//*[local-name() = 'Response']
and
@*//*[local-name() = 'Response']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of

```
//[local-name() = 'Response']
```

use

```
//*[local-name() = 'Response']
```

The predicate (`[]`) needs something to filter on.

`//` selects nothing. It tells to look for any descendant something. But it needs at least a following attribute or node to know what to do.

`/*` selects the root-node independend of name of element

`//*` selects all element-nodes independend of name

`//@` selects all attributes independend of name

`//Response` selects all elements with the name Response that are not in a namespace

`//*[local-name()='Response']` selects all elements with the name Response independend off a namespace

`//*[local-name()='Response' and @ResponseCode='Ok']` selects all elements with the name Response(independend off a namespace) and that have a attribute ResponseCode with the value Ok

Here are some more [examples](https://way2tutorial.com/xml/xpath-axes.php).

And take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241062/3710053)

Comment: Thanks,

Input: //*[local-name() = 'Response']

Output: <RequestID xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">1</RequestID>

I am trying to get the value of the attribute 'Ok', Is there any way to extract that?

Comment: //*[local-name() = 'Response']/@*[local-name() = 'ResponseCode'] -- This worked

Comment: //*[local-name() = 'Response']/@ResponseCode will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `<Response ResponseCode="Ok">` node you can use

```
//Response
```

To extract the `Ok` value from there this should work:

```
//Response/@ResponseCode
```

Comment: How about the namespaces?

Comment: For the given XML I see no need to add nothing. Please correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: The xml is in a namespace. The Xpath wil not select anything. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath/5241062#5241062)